# Provide random item from database

Tags: java, android, database

I have f.e. a thousand names (texts) and I need to show them one by one in random order when I click a button. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Use `ORDER BY RANDOM`.

Comment: I dont have a code.. I just want to know what is the better way to do this.. 
SQlite? ArrayList? or what?

Comment: I dont need code guys. I dont know why u gave negative points. I need to tell me the way to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQLite or Shared Preferences if you need to keep names even after you close the program. Here is the sample code.

```
ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;
SQLiteDatabase database;

dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(context, "DB");
        database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+"names"+
                " ("+"ID"+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                "name"+" TEXT)");
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("name", name_string);

        database.insert("names", null, cv);
database.close();
```

then use Cursor to access values from database:

```
Cursor c = database.query("names", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        String name;
        do{
            int nameCI = c.getColumnIndex("name");
            name = c.getInt(nameCI);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
```

Comment: Thats almost what I need. Lets say I have a hundred contacts. When I click the button a random name will appear. When I click it again another name will appear and the previous will deleted from the list. When I reopen the app the deleted names will not reappear in the list.. I think your way is what I need.. Maybe with a little modification. What do you think?

Comment: well taking random name from the database is easy: generate random number between 0 and number of

Comment: well taking random name from the database is easy: generate random number between 0 and number of name 'Random rand = new Random();

    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((100) + 1;' for example

Comment: to delete the item from the table use: db.execSQL("delete from "+names+" where name='"+your_name+"'");

Answer (score 0):

get all the name from database and store in the array list .You can get the all the name on the onCreate() of the activity or on button click as you wish.

```
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("E");
list.add("I");
list.add("O");
list.add("U");

public void clickEvent(){
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    String name=list.get(0);//from index
    textView.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. You are actually helpful.